# Apache [P] redirect: noDecode % to %25

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-encoding, mod-proxy

I have the following `Rewrite Rule` set to:

```
RewriteRule ^db/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:5984/app/$1 [P]
```

On my `httpd.conf` file I have:

```
AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
```

Where I would like to submit information like this:

```
db/http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2Fwebfonts
```

so Apache will redirect that to

```
http://127.0.0.1:5984/app/http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2Fwebfonts
```

The problem here is that apache is converting occurrences of `%` and replacing with `%25` and transforming the url above into:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5984/app/http%253A%252F%252Fgoogle.com%252Fwebfonts
```

How can I avoid that and redirect exactly what I am sending.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `NE` flag (No Encode) to the rule:

```
RewriteRule ^db/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:5984/app/$1 [P,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jon, unfortunately it seems `NE` will convert `%3A` to `%`, but I think this is already a good start :)?

Comment: How about with an `NE` and a `B`?

Comment: That would convert `%3A%2F` to `%3A%252F` :( crazy isn't it